# Handling keypresses in input type file modal

Tags: javascript, html

My web application uses a keyup event handler to catch Escape key presses and react to them accordingly. One form has a file input and when the user presses escape to close the modal that appears after pressing the Browse button, my keyup event handler is fired and registers that Escape was pressed. Any idea how to prevent that? I thought I could catch the Escape in the input, but it seems that keyup is never fired in the input element itself, so I cannot stop the event from bubbling up. Another idea was to disable my event handler as soon as the user clicks the Browse button, but I cannot reenable it reliably because the onchange event is not always fired in all browsers.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `keypress` event instead of the `keyup` event. "Up" means when you release the key, which is rarely what you want. To know that someone typed a key, `keypress` is better.